# SQL Group rows for every ID using left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, distinct

I have a table with almost a million records of claims for 6 different conditions like Diabetes, Hypertension, Heart Failure etc. Every member has a number of claims. He might have claims with the condition as Diabetes or Hypertension or anything else. My goal is to group the conditions they have(number of claims) per every member row.

**Existing table**

```
+--------------+---------------+------+------------+
|  Conditions  | ConditionCode |  ID  | Member_Key |
+--------------+---------------+------+------------+
| DM           |          3001 | 1212 | A1528      |
| HTN          |          5001 | 1213 | A1528      |
| COPD         |          6001 | 1214 | A1528      |
| DM           |          3001 | 1215 | A1528      |
| CAD          |          8001 | 1823 | B4354      |
| HTN          |          5001 | 3458 | B4354      |
+--------------+---------------+------+------------+
```

**Desired Result**

```
+------------+------+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
| Member_Key | COPD | CAD | DM | HF | CHF | HTN |
+------------+------+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
| A1528      |    1 |     |  2 |    |     |   1 |
| B4354      |      |   1 |    |    |     |   1 |
+------------+------+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

**Query**

```
select distinct tr.Member_Key,C.COPD,D.CAD,DM.DM,HF.HF,CHF.CHF,HTN.HTN
   FROM myTable tr
   --COPD
  left outer join (select Member_Key,'X' as COPD
   FROM myTable
   where Condition=6001) C
  on C.Member_Key=tr.Member_Key
  --CAD
  left outer join ( ....
```

For now I'm just using 'X'. But i'm trying to get the number of claims in place of X based on condition. I don't think using a left outer join is efficient when you are searching 1 million rows and doing a distinct. Do you have any other approach in solving this

Comment: Get familiar with PIVOT function.

Comment: hmmm... PIVOT does not seem like it is needed for a case like this. @KrzysztofKaszkowiak

Comment: You're right. If number of conditions does not change, then PIVOT is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want so many sub-queries, this is easy with group by and case statements:

```
SELECT Member_Key
       SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=6001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COPD,              
       SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=3001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=5001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HTN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=8001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAD
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Member_Key
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an ideal situation for CASE statments:

```
SELECT tr.Member_Key, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=6001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as COPD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Condition=6002 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherIssue,
    SUM(CASE etc.)
FROM myTable tr
GROUP BY tr.Member_Key
```

Comment: nice answer -- have some typos there with the tr alias not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with a PIVOT, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT conditions, member_key
 FROM t) src
 PIVOT
(COUNT (conditions)
 for conditions in ([COPD], [CAD], [DM], [HF], [CHF], [HTN])) pvt
```

Comment: Looks like condition code is an integer. Conditions is a string